# Draw sequence of coloured rectangles with text

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'd like to draw the following figure with latex:

[image]

What would be the right library to use?

Comment: `chains`?  `shapes.multipart`? what you try so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how complex and flexible you want your solution to be.

If you only have binary numbers of two digits (00, 01, 10, 11) you can get away with the `chains` library for the automatic placement in a row and few helpful styles.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  2-bin helper/.code 2 args={#1 #2},
  2-bin 00/.style={fill=cyan!50!green!50},
  2-bin 10/.style={fill=green!50!yellow},
  2-bin 01/.style={fill=red},
  2-bin 11/.style={fill=black, text=white},
  start chain=going right,
  node distance=.1em, inner xsep=.1em, % A is the widest character:
  every on chain/.append style={text width=width("A"), align=center}]
\sffamily
\node[every on chain] at (-5mm,0) {A B};
\foreach \binary in {10,01,10,01,10,01,10,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,11}
  \node[on chain, 2-bin \binary] {\tikzset{2-bin helper/.expand once=\binary}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]